# Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site but it’s the same site

Tags: html, same-origin-policy, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-mode

I have two demo apps on Heroku, let’s call them `a.herokuapp.com` (website) and `b.herokuapp.com` (CDN).

When visiting `a.herokuapp.com` in a browser, request is made for content (media) stored on `b.herokuapp.com`. This, by definition, should be a request to the **same site**, since both are subdomains of the same domain.

However, when I check the actual request the browser makes (Chrome), `Sec-Fetch-Site` is set to `cross-site`, not `same-site`:

```
…
Host: b.herokuapp.com
Origin: https://a.herokuapp.com
Referer: https://a.herokuapp.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out - it behaves as expected. The two URLs aren’t considered “same site”.

See here:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#same-site